# MATLAB-GUI-buttondownfcn, finding value of matrix

Tags: matlab, user-interface

SOLVED i made ACH as global

I have problem in finding the value of a matrix when using `buttondownfcn`. I can find coordinates in axes but not the value because my matrix is animaton and it is changing every 0,01sec. I wanted to save characteristic value in moment of clicking but that function is not able to save it, it writes me :

MouseData with properties:

```
   Source: [1x1 Figure]
EventName: 'ButtonDown'
```

Is there way to find value of matrix by clicking directly? without axes?

This is function for getting coordinates, but i need value ACH, example of ACH is below

```
function [x,y]=pressfcn(~,ACH)
    axes('Parent',hraciepole,...
            'Units','pixel',...
            'Position',[0,0,10000,7000]); 
    suradnice=get(axes,'CurrentPoint'); 
    cislo=suradnice(1,1:2);
    x=cislo(1,1)*70;
    x=round(x)
    y=cislo(1,2)*100;
    y=round(y)
    disp(ACH)


function [hdnt]=hodnota(ACH,x,y)
        disp(hdnt)
        switch hdnt(x,y)
            case {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19}
                d=d+1
                if d==7
                    sprava=sprintf('%d','Vyhrál jsi!');
                    helpdlg(sprava);
                    close all;
                    delete(hraciepole);
                end
        end
    end
end
```

example of ACH and loop

```
pozadie(54,13:20)=postava(1,:);
                ACH=int8(1);
                vykres(pozadie)
                pause(t);
                pozadie(53,13:20)=postava(1,:);
                pozadie(54,13:20)=postava(2,:);
                ACH=int8(2);
                vykres(pozadie)
                pause(t);
                pozadie(52,13:20)=postava(1,:);
                pozadie(53,13:20)=postava(2,:);
                pozadie(54,13:20)=postava(3,:);
                ACH=int8(3);
                vykres(pozadie)
                pause(t);
```

it just changes matrix, "vykres(pozadie)" is function where are defined colors using imshow

Comment: Can you create a callback function for the graphics object that you are clicking on?

Comment: Can you show some code ? At least the parts related to your question.

Comment: and i need to save value ACH when i click on matrix in figure window and then i can work with it

Comment: i have a function, which input is value ACH, it is number from 1 to 150.. And i assigned matrixes to those numbers but i need to get those ACH values.